Jmeter Response time is not matching with Web browser - 'Waiting for Server Response' time
We have facing a typical issue in Jmeter response time.
We have an application, where we are searching for record with a keyword.
Manually when we do the same in browser, we get it around 2-3 secs with single users, whereas when we hit the same request(post) through JMeter we are receiving around 17-20sec for the same single user.
Applied Manage Cookie,Manage Cache & applied same header requests as the browser has and executed the Jmeter script with single user, the load time/Latency time is showing around 17Sec to 20+Sec's,
When we do the same step manually in browser (Chrome/Edge), the 'Waiting for Server Response' time shows around 2-3sec's in same machine where we did the jmeter test.
below are the screenshots of the same.Response time in Browser
Response Time in Jmeter
Unable to understand why jmeter is showing us 17-20sec for same step. Are we missing any configurations or anything else?
Request your suggestions and help on this...

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Normally "typical" situation is that JMeter reports lower response time than the browser does. And normally it's sufficient to configure JMeter to behave like a real browser in order to get similar or even same response times
Some troubleshooting steps I can think of:

Try another HTTP client utility like curl and see how does response time look like
Try running the request after clearing your browsing history including cache
Try enabling JMeter debug logging for Apache HttpComponents and/or Java network debug logging to see what's going on there

